# cannot get Object(or JObject) in asp.net web api with get method and appliction/json

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

**I cannot get Object in asp.net web api method via get method.**

1. if I use post ,it's working
2. if I use get ,it's 'null'
3. my settings:set 'application/json' when I request.

[this is my code screenshots images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FELn.jpg)

Comment: You cannot issue a `GET` request with a request body. Put the object in the url instead as a query string and specify the `[FromUri]` attribute on the get action.

Comment: OK,I think I should use url parameters like this 'http://example.com?json={"aa":"bbb"}' . that I must serialize with Newtonsoft manually.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: No it should be good enough to just do example.com?aa=bbb for an object like `public class MyDto { public string AA {get; set; }}`

Comment: Yeah,you're right.thanks a lot.